# Overlay once per session... Cookie?

Tags: cookies, overlay

I need to open a popup on loading the home page. Each time the home page opens, the popup must appear only once: if the same session goes back to the home page, the popup does not have to open. If I close the browser and open the home page the popup must open.

I am using this code for popup

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#box').fadeIn('slow');

    $(".close").click(
    function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#box').hide();
    });


    $("#overlay").click(
    function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#box').hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a cookie that indicates popup is shown to user then control it in every page. For jQuery;

```
$.cookie("popUpShown", 1, { expires: 1});
```

Then this code below removes cookie when user leave the page. So you can show your modal again.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   $.removeCookie('popUpShown');
});
```

or you can use something like this

```
<body onunload="cookieRemover()">
```

Reference cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

**2020 Update:**

The solution above is obsolete. You can achieve this without cookies, what you are looking for is [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over
>   page reloads and restores.

But if you close the tab and reopen it will be gone.

Comment: How do I link cookie to #overlay? Do I need the plugin you linked?

Comment: Plugin only helps you to manage cookies, read documentation (might have updated) and place a simple if condition that if cookie exists then show your div.